# I am animate the pie chart using Handler event class of google visualization API

Tags: api, google-visualization

```
if (element.Category.ChartType == "PieChart") {
                        console.log(sliceOptions);
                        var animate = 0.05;
                        console.log("for your test" + rows[4][1]);
                        console.log("for your test" + rows[3][1]);
                        console.log("for your test" + rows[2][1]);
                        console.log("for your test" + rows[1][1]);
                         wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                            chartType: element.Category.ChartType,
                            dataTable: rows,     
                            containerId: element.Category.Key,
                            options: {
                               is3D:true, height: 270, slices: sliceOptions,
                                pieStartAngle: 100,
                                animation: { startup: true, duration: 15000, easing: 'Out' },
                                 backgroundColor: '#F8F8FF',
                                pieSliceText: 'label',
                                tooltip: { color: '#FF0000' },
                                slices: {
                                    1: { offset:animate },
                                    2: { offset: animate },
                                    3: { offset: animate },
                                    4: { offset: animate },

                                },

                            }

                        });
                         google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'select', selectHandler);
                         function selectHandler() {
                             //alert('A table row was selected');
                             var data = wrapper.getSelection();
                             alert(data);
                         }

                    }
```

But it throws the above exception.
Uncaught TypeError: wrapper.getSelection is not a function.
I am animate the pie chart using Handler event class of google visualization API.
please provide me solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSelection()` is a *Chart* method, not a *ChartWrapper* method

try this instead...

`wrapper.getChart().getSelection()`